# Hide List view buttons for certain users/profiles salesforce

Tags: apex, list-view, dynamic-forms

Is there a way to hide "New" button, only for certain users / profiles, on the list view of a custom object ?

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no standard way to restrict button visibility on listviews.

Please find the below [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhmjUAB/limit-the-visibility-of-a-custom-button-based-on-profile) for the same

Answer (score 0):

To hide the "New" button on a list view, you can simply remove "Create" rights of this object from a profile. If a user does not have create rights to an object, that user will also not see the "New" button